# Building a URL rules map for MVC Framework

Tags: php

I have built my own PHP MVC Framework after following some tutorials online. I have this all working using an entry script in `.htaccess` as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have a Router class which basically translates the URL and divides it in to action / controller segments:

```
$route = (empty($_GET['rt'])) ? '' : $_GET['rt'];

if (empty($route))
{
    $route = 'index';
}
else
{
    /*** get the parts of the route ***/
    $parts = explode('/', $route);
    $this->controller = $parts[0];

    if(isset( $parts[1]))
    {
        $this->action = $parts[1];
    }
}
```

What I want to do is take this one step further and actually define URL rewriting rules that work in addition to the automatic routing. So basically I want to be able to do something like this:

```
$rules = array(
    'directory/listing/<id>' => 'listing/index',
    'directory/<category>/<location>' => 'directory/view',
);
```

In the above, the array key is the entered URL - the parts in the angle brackets are dynamic variables (like GET variables). The array value is where the request needs to be routed to (controller/action). So for the above two rules we have the following two actions:

```
public function actionIndex($id) {
}

public function actionView($category, $location) {
}
```

So essentially the URL needs to checked against the array keys first, if it matches one of the keys then it needs to use the array value as the controller/action pair.

Anybody have any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: Theres a site I use for some development assistance: http://jream.com/learning/  It's got a step by step video guide on MVC Frameworks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact code you would need to implement this in your environment, but I can mention that this is exactly how Magento's URL rewrites function. Their URLs are structured as `<controller>/<action>/<arguments>`. They even take it one step further and define key/value pairs as URL parameters so `../id/20/meta/25` turns into an array like so:

```
array(
    'id' => 20,
    'meta' => 25
)
```

You could [download their source](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download) and check it out. It may help you head in the right direction: